# Some variables are blank when using cron to run a script

Tags: bash, cron, keep-alive

I'm trying to do a keep alive script to my java process. 
When they are running they create and update a txt with the unix timestamp. The script should check the files in that folder and reboot the process that weren't updated for more than 10 minutes.
When I run the script manually it works fine, but when the cron runs it some variables are blank in the log.
I found some similar questions, but they are all about enviroment variables.
Here is a piece of my code, with the variables that are blank:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
for file in /home/.../keepAlive/*
do
  value=`cat $file`
  echo "File: ${file#/home/.../keepAlive/}"
  date="$(($(date +%s)*1000))"
  dif=`expr $date - $value`
  dif=`expr $dif / 60000`
  echo "Updated $dif minutes ago"
echo "${file#/home/.../keepAlive/} checked at `date` with $dif minutes" >> /home/.../keepAlive.log
if [ $dif -gt '600000' ]
then
(...)
```

Anyone know why the variables $value, $date are blank?
This is the first time I ask a question here, I'm sorry if I did something wrong.
Thank you!

Comment: I don't think its the source of your problem, but there doesn't seem to be a need to change the value of `IFS` for the code you've posted.

Comment: its because the names of the files have spaces, if I don't change the script split all the names.

Comment: Resetting `IFS` is overkill; use `value=$(cat "$file")` instead.

Comment: I found I had to source /etc/profile from my script, right after #!/bin/bash

Answer (score -1):

Percent character has a special meaning in crontab, you need to quote it, so change:

```
date="$(($(date +%s)*1000))"
```

to

```
date="$(($(date +\%s)*1000))"
```

Comment: It's not special in cron *scripts*, it special in the *crontab*

Comment: This, however, is a script that is executed *from* `cron`, not *by* `cron`; the percent sign in the script is only seen by `bash`.